# Handling Android Facebook API's Response Object

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The current Facebook API v3.0.2.b will return a com.facebook.Response object that holds the response. Do you know how to parse this? The following code will raise an Exception :(

```
//execute the request
Request request = new Request
(
    session,
    "/fql",
    params,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new Request.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted( Response response )
        {
            try
            {
                JSONArray json = new JSONArray( response.toString() );
            }
            catch ( Throwable t )
            {
                System.err.println( t );
            }
        }
    }
);
Request.executeBatchAsync( request );
```

The error message says:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated object at character 25 of {Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[{"pic_square":.....
```

Does anybody know what's the correct solution? Shall I use

```
GraphObject go = response.getGraphObject();
```

.. how can I get GraphUser-Objects with that?

Sorry, this seems like a trivial issue but processing the Response-object is poorly documented in the facebook docs and I wasn't able to receive anything about this on the web :(

Thank you very much in advance!

Greetings Christopher

Comment: Try to see value of `response.responseCode` in your `onCompleted` method. Are you able to see 200 there?

Comment: Hi Pratik,
Thanks for your response. Yes - The code is 200 and meanwhile, I've solved this issue :) I'd like to post my solution but I can't answer my own questions yet :(

Comment: Great that you solve your problem. I think you are getting response as object only so no need to convert in string like this `response.toString()`. That's what I want to check with `response.responseCode`.

Comment: The correct order of processing the Response would be:

GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
JSONArray   arr = jso.getJSONArray( "data" );

I'll post an acceptable method in six hours - sorry but my reputation is still too low :)

Thanks anyway

Christopher

Comment: That's good piece of code. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Feel free to upvote my question or it's solution! ;)

Comment: yeah lately but it is helpful to me also +1:)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

this is the solution that worked for me - 
I had to investigate the response and play around a bit with some methods but finally solved it :)

```
/************************************************************************
*   Parses the user data from the facebook FQL
*
*   "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN ( SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() )"
*
*   This is the example query from
*   {@link http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/run-fql-queries/}
*
*   @param  response    The facebook response from the FQL
************************************************************************/
public static final void parseUserFromFQLResponse( Response response )
{
    try
    {
        GraphObject go  = response.getGraphObject();
        JSONObject  jso = go.getInnerJSONObject();
        JSONArray   arr = jso.getJSONArray( "data" );

        for ( int i = 0; i < ( arr.length() ); i++ )
        {
            JSONObject json_obj = arr.getJSONObject( i );

            String id     = json_obj.getString( "uid"           );
            String name   = json_obj.getString( "name"          );
            String urlImg = json_obj.getString( "pic_square"    );

            //...

        }
    }
    catch ( Throwable t )
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps anybody someday.

Greetings

Christopher

**UPDATE**

GraphObject is no longer a class, so just:

```
JSONObject  jso = response.getJSONObject();
JSONArray   arr = jso.getJSONArray("data");
```